# Не видит таблицу SQlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

столкнулся с проблемой. Файл бд лежит в одной дериктории с скриптом. Не понимаю что не так.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

id = 317220077

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?', (id,)).fetchall()


conn.close()
```

трейс: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: accounts

Comment: попробуйте указывать полный путь к файлу БД

Comment: Maxim Timakov , Пробовал. На винде только такая проблема. Пробовал на Ubuntu все отлично работает

Comment: `sqlite` может молча создать новую БД. Вы уверены, что открывается именно нужная?

Comment: Подобное поведение воспроизводится и на Ubuntu, если запускать скрипт из другой директории. при этом в текущей директории создается пустая БД с указанным в скрипте именем.

Comment: А вы прописали "CREATE TABLE.."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобное может происходить, если текущая директория не совпадает с директорией, в которой расположена база данных.

При этом `sqlite` молча создает новую пустую базу данных.

Чтобы этого избежать нужно указывать полный путь к БД.

Для получения директории, в которой расположен скрипт можно использовать следующий код

```py
from os import path

def get_script_dir():
    abs_path = path.abspath(__file__) # полный путь к файлу скрипта
    return path.dirname(abs_path)
```

Получим полное имя файла БД:

```py
DB_NAME = 'db.db'
DB_FILE = get_script_dir() + path.sep + DB_NAME
```

Comment: идиоматичнее использовать `os.path.join(get_script_dir(), DB_NAME)`